# Why GtkWidget is not being found

Tags: gtk, vala

I have following simple application which creates a window with Label, Entry and Button:

```
using Gtk;

public static int main(string[] args) {
    Gtk.init(ref args);             
    var mywin = new MyWindow("Entrypad");   
    mywin.show_all();           
    Gtk.main();                 
    return 0;
}

public class MyWindow : Window{ 
    public MyWindow(string  stitle) {
        this.title = stitle;                    
        this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);    

        var grid = new Grid();  
        this.add(grid);         
        
        var lab = new Label("Mylabel:"); 
        lab.set_xalign(1); 
        grid.attach(lab, 0, 0, 1, 1 );      

        Entry ent = new Entry(); 
        grid.attach(ent, 1, 0, 1, 1 );
        
        var printButton = new Button.with_label("Print Button"); 
        grid.attach(printButton, 0, 1, 1, 1); 
        printButton.clicked.connect( printButtonFn ); 
    }
} 

private void printButtonFn(){   
    print("In print fn; \n"); 
}
```

Above code compiles and works all right.  However, I want to show a dialog box, hence I modify printButtonFn and add code taken from [here](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Dialog.html):

```
private void printButtonFn(){   
    print("In print fn; \n"); 
    quick_message(this, "Message for dialog box."); 
}

// Function to open a dialog box with a message
void quick_message (GtkWindow *parent, gchar *message) {
    GtkWidget *dialog, *label, *content_area;
    GtkDialogFlags flags;
    
    flags = GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT;
    dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons ("Message",
                                          parent,
                                          flags,
                                          _("_OK"),
                                          GTK_RESPONSE_NONE,
                                          NULL);
    content_area = gtk_dialog_get_content_area (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    label = gtk_label_new (message);

    g_signal_connect_swapped (dialog,
                              "response",
                              G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy),
                              dialog);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (content_area), label);
    gtk_widget_show_all (dialog);
}
```

However, above is giving error:

```
$ valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 mysrc.vala 
rnskeletalGUI_dialog_soques.vala:50.21-50.21: error: syntax error, expected identifier
    GtkWidget *dialog, *label, *content_area;
                       ^
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: I think your problem here is the example is actually in C rather than Vala. The documentation is automatically generated from some C sources, so it probably needs tweaking. The example code is the same as for the [C GTK4 example](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Dialog.html)

Comment: Ok! You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Two problems.

First, it's `Gtk.Widget` not `GtkWidget`.  Or, if you have a `using Gtk;` in that code too, you can just use `Widget`.

Second, and the one valac is erroring about, is that unlike C, in Vala the pointer goes with the *type*, not the variable.  So if you want three pointers to `Gtk.Widget` you should write `GtkWidget* dialog, label, content_area;` not `Gtk.Widget *dialog, *label, *content_area;`

That said, you shouldn't be using pointers here. Pointers in Vala basically opt you out of the memory management system, and you should almost never use them... think of it a bit like the "unsafe" keyword in some languages.

Comment: I had just copied the code from demo pages.

Comment: Now `GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT` `gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons` `gtk_dialog_get_content_area` `gtk_label_new` `g_signal_connect_swapped` are not being found!

Comment: That makes sense, since in Vala those would be `Gtk.DialogFlags.DESTROY_WITH_PARENT`, `Gtk.Dialog.with_buttons`, `Gtk.Dialog.get_content_area`, etc.  The code you're copying is in C, not Vala